# React wait variable to load before executing the return

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-router-dom

I'm working on security access to a page with checks where a user is authenticated and is approved to view the page. Where a user is not verified and not approved, they should be redirected to their respective pages.

I have implemented useContext with reducers to store state. and the following is code for a private route that is supposed to appropriately redirect users.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../../context/auth/AuthContext";

const PrivateVerifiedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { isAuthenticated, user, loading } = authContext;

  let isVerified = false;
  let isApproved = false;
  let page;

  if (user) isVerified = user.data.isVerified;
  if (user) isApproved = user.data.isApproved;

  if (isVerified === false) {
    page = "/notverified";
  } else if (isApproved === false) {
    page = "/notapproved";
  } else {
    page = "/";
  }

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (
          <Redirect to={page} />
        ) : isApproved !== true ? (
          <Redirect to={page} />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateVerifiedRoute;
```

The above code seems to be working but not as planned. It appears it's redirecting users before the **user** variable is loaded. hence, all users are being redirected to **notverified** page.

Question is How can do instruct react to wait until user is loaded before it runs the redirecting code?

Comment: You probably need to implement a loading state such that if the user status is unknown that the UI doesn't react just yet, i.e. it doesn't redirect nor allow user though to protected component. Can you update your question to include the `AuthContext` component and logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a "Loading" page or a "loading skeleton" component and redirect/render accordingly when `loading` is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

I have added

```
if (!user && isAuthenticated) return <span>loading...</span>;
```

right before the `return`. And put

```
 useEffect(() => {}, [user]);
```

right after defining `user` from `authContext`. This way the code reruns when `user` has finally loaded. It may not be the best solution but is now serving my purpose.